# A better option than to store db model in a txt file in a php shared hosting environment

Tags: security, file

This is more of a conceptual question rather than a programming question.

I have developed a system where I use a DB layer which is responsible for generating queries as well as running them.

To avoid creating queries which can't run I have a simplified database model over every table with all respective columns of the persistance layer. In each record I provide the name of a table and for each column in the table I provide name, type and length. This way I can catch bad naming problems but also invalid inputs.

The model has no knowledge of data stored in the tables.

The model is stored in a txt file which exists in the filesystem of the server. I am concerned with the security of that solution as typing in the url for the db_model txt file would expose the entire persistence data model of the application.

How can I do a better job with this?

I'm thinking about a few options.

1. encrypt the txt file and then for each session, decrypt and store as a session variable as I need the model for each pageload, even several times on most pageloads.
2. Moving it up in hierarchy of the filesystem above the root of the webserver and read it through ftp connection. It would look bad when packaging the system as a product though so I don't think that option is viable.

Are any of these options a good idea or should I do something completeley different?

best regards
Rythmic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on the RDBMS is definitely an option to consider strongly - another option is to query the DB itself if you feel the need to validate input - ie either store the data in your text file in the db itself and read it through non-parameterised queries or even better, read the DB schema directly from your DB system which will guarantee the version you're checking input against exactly matches your DB schema

Comment: A tad late, but I still think you deserve the credit for an acceptable answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

Don't keep track of it your self. Your RDBMS (which one are you using, btw?) will have an internal mechanism to keep track of this. It also has its own mechanisms for ensuring that the queries you pass to it are acceptable. That's why we pay it the big bucks - let it do its job the way it's trained to.

Comment: I use mysql. And I get that the RDBMS will only accept valid queries. My reason for pre validating is 
1. I don't want truncated data
2. I don't want the normal user to need to fill out forms several times because they didn't understand which format was expected.
Pre-checking this creates the ability to create "intelligent" forms which don't allow invalid inputs. or at least ignore the most obvious ones.
3. I want my DB layer to handle these things with graceful exceptions to provide a better User Experience. As I'm using PHP for this system I feel the mysql_error function is a bit inadequate.

Comment: Unless you're writing an app like phpmyadmin, there's no reason to have the validation logic so closely coupled to the persistence layer. For security reasons (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you don't want your users to be able to run SQL directly in any case.

Comment: That is an issue I will tackle in v2. I haven't worked a lot on prepared statements and there was enough new technology for me to get v1 of the system up and running.

Comment: huh? what does prepared statements have to do with anything? There are plenty of easier ways to prevent SQL injection, but more importantly, I'm confused about the design decisions that would lead you to want to couple the validation logic so closely with the persistence layer.

Comment: I don't really see it as the validation layer. It is more of a help layer to generate forms for objects and to get more information about the db with less code. The validation is done before the persistence layer even sees the data but the validation does not know about the length of all the fields in the database, which could be seen as a flawed design but that can be adressed later. I solved the initial question by hiding the txt file using .htaccess rules. Perhaps a design discussion is more suitable somewhere else. I do appreciate the pointers but they seem slightly out of topic.

Comment: Well, design discussions are more fun. :-) I would argue that part of the job of the validation layer is that if a given field is a VARCHAR(64) in the database, the validation layer should check the length of the input. If the data reaches the persistence layer and is longer than 64 characters, it is no longer user error (for which it would be appropriate to return a pretty error message) but system error.

Comment: I would agree with you on that argument which is why I also use the knowledge of the data fields for creating the forms and accordingly restricting input size. Neverthelesess I need that information in the persistence layer as well as MySQL as far as I know accepts VARCHARS of any length and simply truncates the data to accepted length if the incoming data is too long. And I also agree on design discussions being more fun.